# Simple Static Gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I've started to learn about GridView (XAML) for Windows 8 Store apps. I've used the ItemsPage example to try and have a look at the code.

My aim is use it as a horizontal menu, on the click event it will simply open another xaml page.

I've edited the SampleDataSource.cs file and filled up with the wanted content, i thought that there would be an easier, cleaner way of doing this. This Menu won't be dynamic and won't change so i'm looking for a way to statically add the menu items.

I can do the following to add a simple text entry;

```
<x:String>Item 1</x:String>
```

But i have i'm not sure how to bind to certain parts, such as the image and title elements

Right, i think i'm understanding this a little bit more. The following code would try and bind to itemsViewSource

```
<CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

So would i need to create a new list, such as;

```
List<String> itemsList = new List<string>();
itemsList.Add("Item 1");
itemsList.Add("Item 2");
```

Only issue is that each item (line) would need a Title and Image text field and how to bind those to the correct items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ItemsControl` (`GridView`) needs to display more than one bound item for each list item - you need to bind its Source to a list of something more than a string unless you want to parse the strings. In your case you would have something like

```
List<TitleAndImageText> itemsList = new List<TitleAndImageText>();
itemsList.Add(new TitleAndImageText { Title = "Title 1", ImageText = "Image Text 1");
itemsList.Add(new TitleAndImageText { Title = "Title 2", ImageText = "Image Text 2");
```

Then in your `ItemTemplate`/`DataTemplate` you would have two `TextBlock`s - that bind to the properties of your item view model like this: `Text="{Binding Title}"`, `Text="{Binding ImageText}"`.

Of course you need to define your `TitleAndImageText`, e.g.

```
public class TitleAndImageText
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've managed to get that far on my own by reading various bits around the websites. What you have is pretty much what i have done. With the template that i started off with, it makes use of a CollectionViewSource in the Page.Resources section. It seems like i'm going from the binding on the control to the page.resources at the top then to the another section. Is it necessary to use the CollectionViewSource? thanks

Comment: Does my response answer your question though?

Comment: yes it does to an extent, but i'm happy to mark it as an answer.